# Notation for set minus

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose $\mathcal{A} = \{a,b\}$ or $\mathcal{A} = \{a \}$. Is it ok to write $\mathcal{A} \setminus b$ to indicate 
\begin{cases} 
  \mathcal{A} \setminus b & \text{if } b \in \mathcal{A} \\
  \mathcal{A} & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
If not, what would be an appropriate notation for that?

Comment: I mean: "$\mathcal A\setminus b$" will indicate "$\mathcal A\setminus b$" regardless of what "$\mathcal A$", "$b$" or "$\setminus$" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your intentions when you write $\mathcal A\setminus b$, to the reader $\mathcal A\setminus b$ indicates $\mathcal A\setminus b$ when $b\notin \mathcal A$ as well.

Be mindful of the widespread notation $A\setminus B=\{x\in A\,:\, x\notin B\}$, which carries on in all instances.

Answer (score 5):

Some authors use that notation, but $\mathcal{A}\setminus\{b\}$ is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $A-\{b\}$ or $A\backslash \{b\}$ to denote the set of all elements in $A$ that are not in the set $\{b\}$. This is the set of all elements in $A$ that are not the element $b$. You can use this notation regardless of whether $b$ is an element of $A$ or not.